# Signed_request lost in ASP.NET session, confusing my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 website which is available both from a specific public url, and I'm also making be available as a Facebook App.

Inside my website logic, in some places I have to determine whether the current request is from the Facebook-app, or from the public website, because I want to display content based on this environment.

So, for eg. if the user is using my site as a facebook-app, then I want to display a picture, and if the user is using my site normally, then I don't wanna display a picture.

To determine whether I'm from a Facebook app, I check the "signed_request" in the HttpContext.Request, and store it in the HttpSession to be available for my other actions, not just for that action (url) which is defined for my Facebook app.

So when a child-action is executed, I can determine based on the Session, that the website is used as a FB-app or not.

The problem happens, when the Session times out, because then althought the logic is still running inside Facebook, my logic thinks it's not inside Facebook.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Can you periodically contact the server from the FB-App? Maybe you can "ping" from it if the user does not make any action for a while

Comment: The problem is the my asp.net session times out, and currently this is the bases to determine whether I'm in FB or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it, you can store important information from signed_request in cookie, that expires when browser is closed. Session is not reliable enough to store this content.

I think your approach may be wrong. What if user enters your application both on Facebook and from separate url? Facebook has Javascript API, that places cookies if user is connected to the site. If user is connected, you should display Facebook related content and it shouldn't matter if this is canvas app or separate page. Specially if it uses the same views. If views are not the same, only url, you should have separate urls for canvas app.

Last solution, but horrible is to check in Javascript if page is working in iframe and if it is and signed_request is not present, reload top.location.

Comment: Cookies: if user uses my site from FB I store a cookie. Then, this user uses my site NOT from FB (but from same browser or same browser-tab!), the cookie would still be there, won't it (because my site as a FB-app is still accessed from the same domain as not a FB-app)? Therefore my app will think it's from FB however it's not.

Comment: @Csabi: It is the same with Session. If you want to make a difference, you should have different urls for Facebook. As I said earlier, you should display Facebook related content only if user is connected to application and you don't have to use signed_request for that.

Comment: So, the only solution is to register a different domain for my 'same' website and set this domain in FB app settings? And then I can use cookies, because I have different cookies from myappdomain.com and myapp4facebookdomain.com? In this case myapp4facebookdomain would point to/be alias of myappdomain.com. This is what you advise? :)

Comment: @Csabi: No, definitely not... Domain should stay the same. One solution is to use URLs like `/facebook/...`. Second is to use JavaScript API to detect if user is connected and display different content for connected users.

Comment: But you told me the JavaScript API uses cookies, and cookies are shared between both FB-app and public-site, so it's not the way to go, or am I mising something? With facebook-suffixed-urls, I might determine (from the url) that I'm from FB, I just have to 'hack' my MVC routes to the proper actions, right? And hopefully noone will use my public-site with facebook-suffixed urls... am I correct? :) THx for your huge help!